# How do I make pop-up ads in my apps?

Tags: ads

Can someone please tell me how to make pop-up ads in my apps? I'm using Xcode 5.

Like this: http://i.gyazo.com/5d3efd4f56d9a6c1bd464a9c45c1cfed.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS :-

You can use separate view controller for showing the interstitial ads.

For Android :-

You can use Android dialog for showing the interstitial ads. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Many open source ad SDKs also use the same method for showing interstitial ads.